# What's the trigger condition of Transfer-Encoding: chunked for Tomcat 8

Tags: java, http, tomcat, chunked-encoding

Here is the configuration in the `server.xml` in my tomcat 8.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

and I just find that some RESTful api requests return with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header, some are not. And looks it's not following the rule that I understood before: "the response that content size exceeds a threshold (say 8k) will return with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`"

so my question is that what is the exactly trigger condition of `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`